# Azure Scheduler Service - not showing any jobs

Tags: azure, scheduler, portal

For one of my two Azure scheduler service job collections, the one that is hosted in the South Central US region is having some real problems.  Absolutely nothing shows up now on the Dashboard, Scale, Jobs or History "tabs" (see screen shot).  Is anyone else having similar issues with any of their job collections in this (or any other) Azure region?

(sorry, can't attach an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an issue that was impacting the portal display for jobs with more complex schedules (e.g. on a particular day of the week).

In the meantime, the jobs themselves do not have any issue and will continue to execute as expected.

You can also see the jobs via the powershell cmdlets (can be installed from [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/)):

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureSchedulerJob -JobCollectionName northcentraljc -Location "North Central US"

JobCollectionName : northcentraljc
JobName           : northcentralbing
Lastrun           : 8/4/2014 9:30:01 AM
Nextrun           : 8/11/2014 9:30:00 AM
StartTime         : 5/26/2014 9:30:00 AM
Status            : Enabled
Recurrence        : 1 per Week
Failures          : 0
Faults            : 0
Executions        : 11
EndSchedule       : None
```

As an update: the issue was fixed on ~10 PM (PST) on 8/5/2014.

Comment: It would appear that they (Microsoft) have fixed this issue.  Just checked a minute ago, and my job collection is showing now.